# Solution check request for showing $\cup_{i\in I}M_{i}=\sum_{i\in I}M_{i}$ for family of modules

Tags: solution-verification, modules

The following question is from this post: [Difficulty understanding the proof for showing: $\sum_{i\in I}M_{i}=\sum_{k\in A}(\sum_{i\in I_{k}}M_{i})$ for index family of modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571212/difficulty-understanding-the-proof-for-showing-sum-i-in-im-i-sum-k-in-a) in terms of background notation and theorems. Could someone check if my solution is correct and if I made any mistakes in terms of the use of index of summations. THe corollary this question came from had their use of index of summation depending usage of powerset which i am still not clear on as cited in the linked post.

**Question:** Let $(M_{i})_{i\in I}$ be a family of submodules of an $R$-module $M$.  Suppose that, for every finite subset $J$ of $I$, there exists $k\in I$ such that finite subset $J$ of $I$, there exists $k\in I$ such that $(\forall j\in J)M_{j}\subset M_{k}$.  Show that $\cup_{i\in I}M_{i}$ and $\sum_{i\in I}M_{i}$ coincide.  I have to show that $\cup_{i\in I}M_{i}=\sum_{i\in I}M_{i}$ coincide.

**Proof:**  $(\rightarrow)$  Suppose $m\in \cup_{i\in I}M_{i}$, implies $\exists i_{0} \in I \wedge m\in M_{i_0}$. Let $J=\{i_0\} \wedge J\subset I$.  Then $\sum_{i\in J}M_{i}=M_{i_0}.$  But so $m\in \sum_{i\in J}M_{i}$ and hence $\cup_{i\in I}M_{i}\subset\sum_{i\in I}M_{i}$

$(\leftarrow)$.  Let $J$ be some arbitrary finite subset of $I$ and suppose $m\in \sum_{i\in J}M_{i}$. The family of modules $(M_{i})_{i\in J}$ are closed under addition and satistfies the axiom for a module (not sure if this is phrase correctly here) hence it is a module. By hypothesis, since $J$ is a finite subset of $I$, there exists a $k\in I$ so that for all $i\in J,$ $\sum_{i\in J}M_{i} \subset M_k$, implying $\sum_{i\in I}M_{i} \subset M_k$ for some $k\in I$.  Then $m\in \cup_{k\in I}M_k,$ and so $\sum_{i\in I}M_{i} \subset \cup_{i\in I}M_{i}.$  Along with the forward direction we have shown $\cup_{i\in I}M_{i}=\sum_{i\in I}M_{i}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: @AnneBauval if it is not too much trouble, can I ask if you take a look at my other posts (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572154/solution-check-request-for-showing-cup-i-in-im-i-and-sum-i-in-im-i).  I am just having trouble with the power set notation and I gave an example to illustrate why I am having difficulties.  Also thank you for looking over my solution.

Comment: I shall try but now I am busy for some hours

Comment: @AnneBauval kk.  No problem.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ops I meant (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571212/difficulty-understanding-the-proof-for-showing-sum-i-in-im-i-sum-k-in-a).

Comment: I am not a native english speaker. Please what do "kk" and "ops" mean?

Comment: @AnneBauval ops is an expression meaning you made a mistake.  Kk is short for okay.